# Read lines from input stream with ability to skip chunks

Tags: c++, stream

I have an input stream with a series of bytecode-like instructions

```
function foo
push x
pop y
...
return
function bar
...
return
function other
...
```

I.e. a series of function declarations back-to-back. Each function is defined from one "function" until the next. There may be multiple "returns" within a function so I cannot use that as a delimiter. All instructions must be inside a function (i.e. the first line of the stream is always a "function" and the last line is always a "return").

I want to basically remove certain functions from the list. I have a list of the functions I want to keep and I thought about copying to an output stream, skipping over any function not on the list, something like

```
vector<string> wanted_functions = { "foo", "other" }
ostringstream oss;
bool skip = false;
for (string line; getline(input_stream, line);) {
    istringstream iss(line);
    string command;
    iss >> command;
    if (command == "function") {
        skip = false;
        string function_name;
        iss >> function_name;
        if (std::find(wanted_function.begin(), wanted_functions.end(), function_name) 
                 == wanted_functions.end()) {
            skip = true;
        }
    if (!skip) oss << line;
}
```

I haven't tested the above solution; it looks like it may work but I don't think it's very elegant.
I feel like stream iterators would be good here but I don't know how to use them. How can I achieve the skipping behavior using iterators, or maybe native stream methods like ignore() or seekg()?

Bonus: If there's a better way to read the first two words in the line that creating a new stream just for them I'd also like to know please.

Edit: Functions are always sequential. There are no nested functions. I.e. "function" is always immediately preceded by "return".

Comment: you could refactor it into multiple functions or a class to make it a bit easier to read but the logic would have to essentially be the same

Comment: Can you have nested functions, or is it always `function ... stuff ... return function ... stuff ... return`?

Comment: @FireLancer They are always in sequence; no nested functions.

Comment: What about conditions / multiple returns? `function ... if ... return else ... return function ...next...`

Comment: @FireLancer as I mentioned, there may be multiple conditional returns in a single function, which is why it cannot be used as a delimiter. This is low-level bytecode, so if-else statements are actually implemented as different types of jumps. The jumps themselves shouldn't matter though. The solution should copy or exclude everything from (and including) the current "function" up until (and excluding) the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's text, you can't easily just jump/skip (`seekg`) without actually reading it since you don't have a known offset to go to (many binary file formats will contain such information), but you can just filter what you do read, the code in your question nearly does this.

`istream_iterator<std:string>` will give you each word / white-space delimited, but you can't tell where the new lines are. You can make a `istream_iterator` that will read lines instead, but the simplest way involves sub-classing `std::string` to redefine `operator >>`, but that is basically what `getline` gets you anyway, or you might make your own type containing more useful information (below).

---

You might use `std::unordered_set<std::string> wanted_functions` as that is easier to check if an item exists or not than searching a `std::vector` (with `std::find` or similar). `skip` also ends up working slightly weirdly as you are setting it on "unwanted" functions, then doing like `if (!unwanted)`.

```
unordered_set<string> wanted_functions = { "foo", "other" };
bool is_wanted_function = false;
for (string line; getline(input_stream, line);) {
    istringstream iss(line);
    string command;
    iss >> command;
    if (command == "function") {
        string function_name;
        iss >> function_name;
        is_wanted_function = wanted_functions.count(function_name) != 0;
    }
    if (is_wanted_function) {
        oss << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

An alternative to the `is_wanted_function` flag would be to consume the function within the `if (command == "function") {`, this needs some more careful management of reading the next line, so as to not accidentally skip the one following the inner loop

```
unordered_set<string> wanted_functions = { "foo", "other" };
string line;
getline(input_stream, line);
while (input_stream) {
    istringstream iss(line);
    string command;
    iss >> command;
    if (command == "function") {
        string function_name;
        iss >> function_name;
        if (wanted_functions.count(function_name)) {
            oss << line << std::endl;
            while (getline(input_stream, line) && line.rfind("function", 0) != 0) {
                oss << line << std::endl;
            }
            continue; // already have a line
        }
    }
    getline(input_stream, line); // next line
}
```

As is I don't think that that is much of an improvement, but if the actual parsing (`iss >> command;`, `iss >> function_name`, etc.) was refactored out elsewhere, then it would be somewhat simpler.

---

You might make the actual parsing (getting the command name like "function", and arguments like "foo") it's own class which can tidy up having the `istringstream iss(line); iss >> command;` etc. being directly in this code.

`istream_iterator` basically just uses `operator >>` to get the next item until the stream is in a failure state, so can be used with your own types, although you can get something very similar doing largely the same yourself without `istream_iterator`.

```
class command
{
public:
    const std::string &cmd()const { return _cmd; }
    const std::string &source_line()const { return _source_line; }
    const std::string &arg(size_t i)const
    {
        if (i < _args.size()) return _args[i];
        else throw std::out_of_range("Command does not have this many arguments.");
    }

    friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is, command &cmd)
    {
        if (std::getline(is, cmd._source_line))
        {
            std::stringstream ss(cmd._source_line);
            ss >> cmd._cmd;
            cmd._args.clear(); // istream_iterator uses the same command object every time
            while (true)
            {
                std::string val;
                ss >> val;
                if (!ss) break;
                cmd._args.push_back(std::move(val));
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
private:
    std::string _source_line;
    std::string _cmd;
    std::vector<std::string> _args;
};
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::stringstream input_stream(
        "function foo\n"
        "push x\n"
        "pop y\n"
        "...\n"
        "return\n"
        "function bar\n"
        "...\n"
        "return\n"
        "function other\n"
        "...\n"
        "return\n");
    std::ostream &oss = std::cout;

    std::unordered_set<string> wanted_functions = { "foo", "other" };
    std::istream_iterator<command> eos; // end of stream
    std::istream_iterator<command> it(input_stream); // iterator
    while (it != eos)
    {
        if (it->cmd() == "function" && wanted_functions.count(it->arg(0)))
        {
            do
            {
                oss << it->source_line() << std::endl;
            } while (++it != eos && it->cmd() != "function");
        }
        else ++it; // on true the while loop already advanced
    }
}
```

`istream_iterator` of course does also bring compatibility with the other iterator based algorithms and constructors (`std::find`, etc.), and you can build some more complex things out of that. For example if you add another layer on top of this to create a `istream_iterator<function>`, then maybe you could use the Boost C++ `filter_iterator`, and then you will have an iterator with just the functions you want.

---

Note that if you need to start dealing with any nested constructs (like `if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... }`), you might find parsing into a tree structure more convenient to do operations on than a flat sequence. See Abstract Syntax Tree. This somewhat depends on your syntax, e.g. if you use just `goto if` offset/label instead of `while(expr)`, `if(expr)`, `else if`, `else`, etc. type constructs.

Comment: Lot's of great suggestions. I realized I was already parsing into a struct later on in the program, so i moved that up and used the third solution.